# Setup Alexa Skill intents and slot types for lambda function

Tags: aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit, alexa-slot

I'm trying to get this [Alexa Skill example](https://github.com/ink-su/apl-factskill) to work. I uploaded the .ZIP to a Lambda function like described in the ReadMe.
How to add the correct *Slot Types*, *Intents* to the Skill in the [Alexa Console](https://developer.amazon.com/alexa/console/ask)?

Comment: Could you elaborate on the trouble that you are facing?

Comment: I get this error after launching the skill through the invocation name if I test it in the developer console: **I'm sorry, I didn't get that. Try asking get me a shape.** If I ask for a **cube** I get the same error again. I expected to get the page of the cube displayed. How to set this intent up?